# Rust missing libraries while linking static C libraary

Tags: c, rust, static, lib

I have encountered problem with linking static lib - when there no windows.h and calls to WinAPI, it links and works fine, but when they used, I get this error when building:

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1120
note: external-test.lib(library_win32.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MessageBoxW referenced in function init_window
```

In list of all used libs, there no user32.lib. Maybe it is the problem? How can I tell linker to use it

```
note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" ... "kernel32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
```

Here build script:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}/src/external",env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap());
}
```

Comment: Try adding `#[link(name = "user32")]` to your `extern "C"` block or somewhere else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution was simple - link user32 in build script